# value field name after raster to polygon conversion

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox, raster-conversion

When I perform *Raster to polygon* conversion using tool, sometimes it creates a field named "GRIDCODE", sometimes the field name is "grid_code". Why does it create random name of a field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online help for **[Raster To Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Raster_to_Polygon/001200000008000000/)** says:

> The Field parameter allows you to choose which attribute field of the
>   input raster dataset will become an attribute in the output feature
>   class. If a field is not specified, the cell values of the input
>   raster (the VALUE field) will become a column with the heading
>   Gridcode in the attribute table of the output feature class.

However, I ran a test using it on a PNG image with an output file geodatabase feature class and a field called **grid_code** was created so the documentation seems to be in error or at least deficient.

I have not been able to find a procedure that will produce a field called **GRIDCODE** or **Gridcode**.

Comment: Thanks. It was my mistake. I was doing raster to polygon using both *Raster To Polygon* tool and `IConversionOp.RasterDataToPolygonFeatureData` Method to test if I my code doing right thing or not. Tool gave "grid_code" and code gave "GRIDCODE". Because of I ran those two simultaneously and add some exceptional case to test, I thought because of those cases, this random thing happened.